# Pass object argument through FAST API

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I have question about FAST API, coz I can't understand some stuff, and documentation is not clear for me.

I have example program:

```
import json
import argparse


def args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Some argumets")
    parser.add_argument("--name", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--surname", type=str, nargs='?', default="Dan")
    parser.add_argument("--birthday", type=str, nargs='?', default="1995")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


class Simple():


    def create_df(self, name, surname, birthday):

        x = {"name": name, "surname": surname, "bd": birthday}

        x = json.dumps(x)

        return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args_all = args()
    s = Simple()
    print(f"name: {args_all.name}, surname: {args_all.surname}, birthday:{args_all.birthday}")
    print(s.create_df(args_all.name, args_all.surname, args_all.birthday))
```

I can run it by:

```
python app.py --name=Matt --surname=Dan  #And let's say that birthday is 1995 is default one.
```

And got working string Matt Dan 1995

And now I want that expose it by FAST API for users. It could create request like:

```
www.api_adress.domain/names?name=Anthony&birthday=33
```

expect result: run function with arguments:

> name=Anthony, surname=Dan, birthday=33

So as U can see I need to have some default values but could be change by user.

My api_code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app_code import *

app = FastAPI()

o = Simple()
args = args()

name = args.name
surname = args.surname
birthday = args.birthday

print(args)

@app.get("/names")
async def root(name=args.name, surname=args.surname, birthday = birthday.args.birthday):
    print("In progress...")
    result = Simple.create_df(name=name, surname=surname, birthday=birthday)
    return result
```

And of course I tried many configurations (and still looking for solution), but still got error like:

```
←[33mWARNING←[0m:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
usage: Some argumets [-h] [--name NAME] [--surname [SURNAME]] [--birthday [BIRTHDAY]]
Some argumets: error: unrecognized arguments: main_api:app --reload
```

I have some problems to understand that, and trying to figure it out. How to pass arguments like normal program with some default values? So if somebody could explain me it, I will be gratefull!

::::EDIT::::

I changed API to:

```
@app.get("/names")
async def root(name: str, surname: str = "Dan", birthday: str = "2020"):
    print("In progress...")
    result = Simple.create_df(name=name, surname=surname, birthday=birthday)
    return result
```

And now I got error:

```
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Uvicorn running on ←[1mhttp://127.0.0.1:8000←[0m (Press CTRL+C to quit)
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Started reloader process [←[36m←[1m20260←[0m] using ←[36m←[1mwatchgod←[0m
←[33mWARNING←[0m:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
usage: Some argumets [-h] [--name NAME] [--surname [SURNAME]] [--birthday [BIRTHDAY]]
Some argumets: error: unrecognized arguments: main_api:app --reload
```

::::EDIT2 ---  WORKING SOULTION! ::::

my api.py python file woks fine. Thanks for comments.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app_code import *
from pydantic import *

app = FastAPI()

o = Simple()


@app.get("/names")
async def root(name: str, surname: str = "Dan", birthday: str = "2020"):
    print("In progress...")
    result = o.create_df(name=name, surname=surname, birthday=birthday)
    return result
```

Comment: You'll can describe your request as Pydantic model - where you can give default values for a field if none is provided (when the request has a JSON body), or you can give a default value in the view definition for GET requests: `def names(name: str, surname: str = 'Dan', birthday: int = 1995):`

Comment: @MatsLindh thank u for suggestion, I will read about pydantic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for MatsLindh answer I changed my api code, and everything works according suggestion. Solution in question - section EDIT2